# Can function be defined with different calling convention in c?

Tags: c, calling-convention

```
int _cdecl    f (int x) { return 0; }
int _stdcall  f (int y) { return 0; }
```

After name mangling will be:

```
_f
_f@4
```

Which doesn't conflict, is this allowed in c ,if not, why?

Comment: It is important to distinguish between C, a standardized abstract language, and Microsoft C (or gcc C, or Borland C, or ...), which are specific, concrete languages. No, this is not allowed in C. Yes, this is allowed in Microsoft C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keywords `_cdecl` and `_stdcall` are not part of the C language.  These are Microsoft extensions which were preceded by similar Borland extensions.

In the standard C language, you can't declare a calling convention.  Every function declared is, obviously, equivalent to what the MS compiler refers to as the "`_cdecl`" convention.

It would be possible to use in-line assembly to distinguish the two functions when you call them.  Because you're using a platform-specific vendor extension of C, you might consider using in-line assembly.

Comment: @Heath I wasn't aware that standard C specified calling conventions, not even cdecl. Am I wrong?

Comment: @David -- The C standard specifies variable arguments, which, for stack based implementations, usually is accomplished by right-to-left argument passing.  Also, in C the caller must clean up arguments because it is possible for the caller to supply extraneous (i.e. too many) arguments.  This is the convention that MS named "_cdecl".  The alternative, _stdcall, was called by Borland "Pascal convention" and pushes arguments from left-to-right.  The callee cleans the stack and variable arguments are not possible.

Comment: @David -- Of course the first sentence of my answer makes it clear that _cdecl is not part of C at all.  What I mean is that _cdecl is the MS name for the C calling convention on x86, as it is implemented by essentially all x86 C compilers.  If MS ported their compiler to another ABI, _cdecl would no doubt continue to refer to the platform-native C calling convention.

Comment: @Heath The C standard does indeed mandate the ability to pass variable numbers of arguments. But does it specify all that is needed for a calling convention? I remain sceptical but prepared to be proved wrong!

Comment: @David - No, of course it doesn't specify the C ABI for the platform.  Did I ever state that it does?  All I'm saying is that "_cdecl" is, by definition, the usual C ABI convention for that platform -- simply because that's what MS defines it to be.  MS has already ported this keyword to many non-x86 platforms (MIPS, SPARC, DEC Alpha, ARM, M68000, etc.) and have been consistent in what _cdecl means.  In particular, _cdecl supports var args and caller cleans up, _stdcall does not.  That's the definition of them, per MS.

Comment: @Heath ,why _stdcall doesn't support var args and caller cleans up?

Comment: @compile-fan: By MS' definition, it doesn't.  Mechanically: on x86, the arguments are pushed onto the stack, then the return address, then control is transferred.  The callee can find its return address and whatever argument is right next to it.  It can read "up" the stack to find the other arguments.  Take the example of printf() -- how would printf() detect that it had reached the format string, if the format string were at the *end* of parameters?  No, the format string is directly adjacent to return address.  Then printf() reads format string.  From format string, printf() calculates ...

Comment: ... how many more arguments from the stack it will read.  The determination of where arguments end on stack is defined by format string, so that parameter is most important.  In C language, by K&R or standards, the '''...''' for variable arguments always comes at end of parameter list.  In summary, C arguments on x86 are pushed right-to-left, then the return address is pushed.  If caller provides: printf("%d", 5, 6); there is know way for printf() to determine that an extra argument, 6, was pushed.  This is why caller must clean up -- caller knows what caller pushed, but callee cannot tell.

Comment: _stdcall is faster because callee cleans up -- so clean-up code is in one place rather than many (smaller size) and can use instructions like '''ret 8''' and '''leave''' to adjust stack.  _stdcall cannot support variable arguments because arguments are pushed left-to-right.  Be aware that parameter evaluation order may be different than order pushed on stack -- no guarantee what order expressions evaluate before being pushed.

Answer (score 1):

First off, that's not mangling, that's decoration. Mangling is something that happens with C++ compilers because C++ was originally designed to to support overloading using C style link tools.

As to your question, you can't have two functions with the same name.  For the purposes of applying that rule, the un-decorated name is used.

Why is this so?  I'd imagine it is because decoration and calling conventions are not part of the C standard and are specific to each compiler.  I'm pretty sure that C compilers supporting multiple calling conventions only came in to being a number of years after C was invented.